# Problem in C. printf ("% ld% ld% ld \ n", lol, & lol, * lol);

Tags: c

who can solve this exercise, so I can understand where I'm wrong because there are too many LOL variables.

Produce a C code that, put before the following expression

```
printf ("% ld% ld% ld \ n", lol, & lol, * lol);
```

print out 3 identical numbers on stdout

Comment: `who can solve this exercise` statements like this are considered offensive on stack overflow community.

Comment: `void** lol; lol = &lol;`

Comment: why use a double voip pointer?

Comment: **Undefined Behaviour**: according to the first (conversion specifier, object), `lol` has type `long int`. You can't apply conversion specifier `"%ld"` to address of long int value, you cannot apply unary operator `*` to value of type `long int` ... the same reasoning applies to the second or third (conversion specifier, object)

Comment: How should we know where you are wrong if you do not show what you have found out so far?

Comment: You could make it a function. But printing a function address with %ld isn't well-defined. Anyway, you need to provide your own solution so far.

Comment: giannni, Are you certain the format is _exactly_ spaced as `"% ld% ld% ld \ n"`?

Comment: "because there are too many LOL variables." is incorrect.  The first problem is that the format for `printf()` leads to undefined behavior as it is ill-formed.

Answer (score 3):

One answer is `#define printf(...) puts("1 1 1")`

The prove :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

#define printf(...) puts("1 1 1\n")
  printf ("% ld% ld% ld \ n", lol, & lol, * lol);

  return 0;
}
```

execution :

```
1 1 1
```

as requested that prints out 3 identical numbers on stdout

Comment: @Jabberwocky sure the proposal of  Blaze  is more interesting ^^

Comment: Actually IMO correct solution can be only be obtained via macro trickery (like this answer), other "non trick" solutions necessarily include UB.